Proving that a natural cubic spline optimizes a smoothing problem
The GAM book by Hastie and Tibshirani 1990 claims that the natural cubic spline is the function $f$ which minimizes the least squares objective
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-f(x_i))^2 +\lambda\int_a^b f''(t)^2dt
$$
They give this as an exercise, where they define the Langrangian functional
$$F(f) = \int_a^b f''(x)^2dx +\rho\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-f(x_i))^2 - \sigma +z^2\right]
$$
($\sigma$ is some slack variable, and $z$ is an "auxiliary" variable) and give some hints:

They also refer to Reinsch 1967.
How do I prove section (i)?
I assume (i) doesn't involve $\sigma$ and $z$. This is my derivation so far, but if you have a better one, please tell me!
If I focus on the 1st term in $F$, after adding $\delta h(x)$, differentiating by $\delta$ (and equating $\delta=0$, which they didn't mention) I'm left with
$$ 2\int_a^b f''(x)h''(x)dx = 2\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f''(x)h''(x)dx
$$
Since $h$ is only twice differentiable, I assume the integration by parts is done to find the anti-derivative of $h$. Doing so, twice, results in:
$$ =  2\sum_{i=1}^n \left[f''(x)h'(x)|_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} - f'''(x)h(x)|_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} +\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f''''(x)h(x)dx\right]
$$
Since $h(x)$ is an arbitrary function, I can somehow reason why $f''''(x)=0 \; \forall x$. Doing the same thing for the 2nd term of $F$ will result in
$$2\rho\sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)-y_i)h(x_i)$$
So I can infer from this that the $f'''({x_i}_-)-f'''({x_i}_+)=\rho \cdot (y_i-f(x_i))$
Maybe I can somewhat reason that $f''$ must also be equal at the knots. But, what about $f'$?

I will show this some other way, in place of your reference following the elements of statistical learning, where this is exercise 5.7.  The solution indicated there is somewhat different , in reality first finding an interpolation spline, and then use that to solve the smoothing problem.
Given $a < x_1 < x_2 < \dotso < x_N < b$ (with $N \ge 2$) and values $f(x_i)$ at the knots. Show that an interpolating function $g$ defined on $[a, b]$ minimizing $\int_a^b g''(t)^2 \; dt$ is a natural cubic spline.

Let $\tilde{g}$ be any other interpolating and differentiable function on $[a, b]$, and $h = \tilde{g} - g$. Then (partial integration)
$$
  \int_a^b g''(t) h''(t) \; dt = -\int_a^b g'''(t) h'(t)\; dt \\
  = -\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} g'''(x_j) \int_{x_{j}}^{x_{j+1}} h'(t)\; dt \\
  = -\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} g'''(x_j)\left\{ h(t_{j+1}-h(t_j) \right\} =0
$$
The first equality uses the condition that $g$ is a natural spline, so its second derivative is zero at $a, b$. The second splits the integration on subintervals and uses the fact that the third derivative of a cubic polynomial is a constant. The third follows since $h=0$ at the knots.


$$
  \int_a^b \tilde{g}''^2 =\int_a^b (g'' + h'')^2 \\
  =\int_a^b g''^2 + 2\int_a^b g'' h'' +\int_a^b h''^2 \\
  = \int_a^b g''^2 + \int_a^b h''^2 \ge \int_a^b g''^2
$$
(and there can be equality only if $h''$ is zero on $[a, b]$, meaning that $h$ must be linear, such that it could be incorporated in the natural cubic spline $g$). Finally

The optimization problem
$$
\min_f \left[ \sum_1^N (y_i - f(x_i))^2 +\lambda \int_a^b f''(t)^2\; dt  \right]
$$
the solution $f$ must be a natural cubic spline. Suppose we have found some candidate solution $f$. Replace it by some natural cubic spline $g$ that interpolated $f$ at the knots, then the first term in the criterion is unchanged, while the second is lowered, unless $f$ already is a natural cubic spline.

